# The multi-part identifier could not be bound 4

Tags: sql

I am trying to join a series of tables but have encountered an error. I have tried applying other Stack Overflow answers to my problem, but to no avail. I'm very new to SQL.

```
select gbkmut.artcode, gbkmut.warehouse, gbkmut.facode, Items.costpricestandard,  ic.DateStart, SUM(aantal)as stockQty  

FROM gbkmut
INNER JOIN Items AS ic ON ItemNumbers.ItemCode=ic.ItemCode
INNER JOIN Items ON Items.GLAccountDistribution = gbkmut.reknr
```

Below is my error

> The multi-part identifier "ItemNumbers.ItemCode" could not be bound.

If it's not clear, `gbkmut`, `ItemNumbers`, and `Items` are the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified `ItemNumbers.ItemCode` in `ON` clause but you have not used `ItemNumbers` table in any Inner join.To use `ItemNumbers.ItemCode` you need to inner join with `ItemNumbers` Table.

```
FROM gbkmut
INNER join ItemNumbers ON condition
INNER JOIN Items AS ic ON ItemNumbers.ItemCode=ic.ItemCode
INNER JOIN Items ON Items.GLAccountDistribution = gbkmut.reknr
```

Comment: To extend your answer, he also need to use `GROUP BY` to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Do I need to join `ItemNumbers` on `gbkmut` or on `Items`? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Also Suvendu, I do have the `Group By` in my original code, but did not include to keep things succinct. Good catch though!

Comment: If `gbkmut` is parent table and `ItemNumbers` is child table then you can use `gbkmut` to join with `ItemNumbers`.

Comment: I see. To aid my understanding, is it also possible to join `ItemNumbers` with 'Items` despite `gbkmut` being the parent table?

Comment: Yes,it is possible to join `ItemNumbers` with `Items`.